# How to Hide Component? Using Timer and onPress without erratic behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, timer

On my screen, I want the user to be able to tap the screen in order to display a `<TouchableWithoutFeedback>` component. Once that component is displayed, I want it to disappear after 4 seconds. That works fine. Also, I want the user to be able to tap the new component to hide it as well. So it hides either by timer or by user touch. Instead of getting that behavior, I'm getting an unexpected one. When I tap the screen the first time, it displays, touch again after 1 sec, it hides, touch again after 1 sec, it displays, then it hides again immediately. I believe that the timer is running no matter if the state is true or not. I tried using a `clearTimeout` but either I'm not using it properly or that's not the solution. Any answers? Thanks! Here's some code:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    showPlayerControls: false
  }
};


showPlayerControls () { this.setState({ showPlayerControls: true, }); }

hidePlayerControls () { this.setState({ showPlayerControls: false, }); }

hideWithTimer() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.hidePlayerControls()
  }, 4000)
}

render() {

  this.state.showPlayerControls ? this.hideWithTimier() : null

  return(
    <View>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.showPlayerControls()} />
      {this.state.showPlayerControls ? (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.hidePlayerControls()} />
      ) : null }
    </View>
  )

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to approach this would be to move the initialization of the timeout from `render` to `showPlayerControls`. Render shouldn't cause any side-effects like setting state unless it occurs due to a user interaction.

Once you've done that, you can use `clearTimout` inside of `hidePlayerControls` to ensure that any time the user clicks the hide node, the timer stops.

Probably unrelated to your issue, but there is a typo in the render method (this.hideWithTim**i**er instead of this.hideWithTimer.)

Here's a working example in code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/qq8mq777mq

Comment: Thanks! I think that may have done it.. in your code pen, I noticed that you declared `timer` within the class but outside of the constructor. does that matter? in terms of organization

Comment: No problem! Ah yeah that's just a style preference, and being able to do that as I did may depend on your babel settings. Either the way I did it or in the constructor should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you not using clearTimeout properly.

Edited: I see, your main problem is **call this.hideWithTimier in render**.

After setState, component will re-render and this function will be call again, and will spawn a new timer to do your function. It make your hand action can not be done. And in long time will flood memory

Move out it from render and set it to your showPlayerCotrol function

setTimeOut return a reference of Timeout instant, take it by your class varialble and use it to clear

```
this._hidePlayCotrolTimer = setTimeOut()
```

when you hidden your commponent by hand. Call clearTimeout.

```
clearTimeout(this._hidePlayCotrolTimer)
```

Dont forget to call clear timer when component unMout to prevent memory leak

```
componentWillUnmount(){
   clearTimeout(this._hidePlayCotrolTimer)
}
```

Or use `react-native-timer-mixin` to auto handle it